# How to call double click on an click event on another element?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a simple inline editing tool using a HTML table and jQuery. When a row is double clicked the value of that cell can be edited. The double click event is like this:

```
$(document).on("dblclick", "." + table + " td", function(e) {   
    if (column <= columns.length) {
        var text = $(this).html();
        input = createInput(column, text);
        $(this).html(input);
        $(this).find(inputs).focus();
        tdediting = 1;
    }
});
```

Now I'm trying to implement a custom menu that will show on right click of mouse. I've created a custom menu with Copy, Edit and Delete options. Now I would like to trigger this `dblclick` event when the edit menu is clicked. How can I do that?

This is the edit menu HTML form:

```
<li class="context-menu__item">
    <a href="#" id="txtedit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>      
</li>
```

I tried the [jQuery trigger event](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) but it didn't worked as expected.

Comment: Could you show your code for the right click event?

Comment: Please check it [here](http://pastebin.com/QwQwETpX)

Comment: This is impossible to follow, please provide a [mcve] and include HTML.